# About the discriminant

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $D=disc(1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \cdots, \alpha^{n-1})$. Let $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_{n-1} \in \mathbb{Q}$ be some constants.

> What is the relation between $disc(1, \dfrac{\alpha}{\lambda_1}, \cdots, \dfrac{\alpha^{n-1}}{\lambda_{n-1}})$ and $D=disc(1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \cdots, \alpha^{n-1})$? Can we express $disc(1, \dfrac{\alpha}{\lambda_1}, \cdots, \dfrac{\alpha^{n-1}}{\lambda_{n-1}})$ in a function deponding on $D$ and  $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_{n-1}$?

---

I know how to compute the discriminant of $(1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \cdots, \alpha^{n-1})$ via Trace, Norm, and the formula $(-1)^{\binom{n}{2}} Nr_{K(\alpha)/K}(f'(\alpha))$, where $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, and $\deg(f)=n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also compute the discriminant by the first definition you find here ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant_of_an_algebraic_number_field) and you can easely see that if $\lambda_i$ are in $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ like in your case by linearity:

\begin{equation}
disc(1, \frac{\alpha_1}{\lambda_1}, \dots , \frac{\alpha^n}{\lambda_n-1}) =\frac{1}{(\lambda_1\cdot \dots \lambda_{n-1})^2}D
\end{equation}

Comment: Of course the discriminant we're using is defined over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=n$. If you're not in this case then you'll have that both of the expressions are $0$.

Comment: If we consider the Trace formula for the discriminant, then it only suffices to factor $\lambda_i$'s once from the rows, and one from the columns. So your formula follows. Thank you so much for your very clear answer.